# Take out status bar from xml style item

Tags: android, xml, animation, statusbar, android-styles

This is the style that I need to use for a popup that I have in the app.
This particular page, is a video view, and it's full screen. so I have no status bar.
But when the popup appears. It appears with the status bar, which is annoying. How can I disable it?

This is my xml:

```
 <style name="ShowPopupNoTitle">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoDisplay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ShowPopupAnimation</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

As you can see, I added the windowActionBar as false. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove `statusBar`,try this in your **java code** in the `onCreate()` method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Yes, I feel so stupid now. I thought it was necesarry to have it in the xml in the styles where I set the animation. But apparently it works if I set that on my dialog's window